# Disable Spring Security for testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to create a Spring profile called `no-security`. As the name suggests, this profile would "disable" (disable may come in different forms, i.e. auto-configuration exclusion or permiting all requests) security.

I have my endpoints secured in 2 ways. When the endpoint requests body - `@RequestBody` - then I secure it in the Security Config class using, for instance, `.requestMatchers(SOME_METHOD,SOME_ENDPOINT).hasAnyAuthority(ACCOUNTANT_AUTHORITIES)`. If the endpoint does not require a body, then it's secured using `@PreAuthorize` annotations.

Now, when the tests are being executed, I want both forms of authorization to become disabled.

I've been playing around with that for an hour or so and I seem to be stuck. Here's the main, production class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    private final CookieAuthenticationFilter cookieAuthenticationFilter;

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    private static final String[] ACCOUNTANT_AUTHORITIES = new String[]{"ADMIN", "ACCOUNTANT"};

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 8)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint))
                .exceptionHandling(excHandler -> excHandler
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                        .accessDeniedHandler(authenticationEntryPoint))
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        // secured endpoints that request a valid body
                        // needs to be specified below
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/entity").hasAnyAuthority(ACCOUNTANT_AUTHORITIES)
                        // ... more endpoints
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManager -> sessionManager
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(cookieAuthenticationFilter, JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Now, in the `test` folder I specified another security configuration class with `SecurityFilterChain` bean overriden (I've enabled bean overriding for tests).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("no-security")
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
public class DisabledSecurityConfig {

    @MockBean
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @MockBean
    CookieAuthenticationFilter cookieAuthenticationFilter;

    @MockBean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @MockBean
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And here's an example of a call to my Rest API:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import({DisabledVaadinContext.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"main", "no-security"})
@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.Random.class)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    void simpleTest() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate
                .exchange("/api/entity", HttpMethod.DELETE, null, String.class);
        String body = response.getBody();
        HttpStatusCode code = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo(EXPECTED_BODY);
        assertThat(code).isEqualTo(200);
    }
}
```

I always end up with `200 OK` and null response body. How do I get this disabling thing working? I'd welcome any suggestions and explanations! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as usual, turned out to be a little more complicated.

As you may have noticed by the `@Import(DisabledVaadinContext.class)` annotation, I use Vaadin in this project. In the tests, however, Vaadin is useless most of the time. Vaadin is also time-consuming at launch and disabling it makes Spring Boot context reload about 5-7 seconds faster.

When this configuration class was not used, then the tests would run perfectly fine, but much, much longer.

The `DisabledVaadinContext` class looked like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        VaadinScopesConfig.class,
        SpringBootAutoConfiguration.class,
        SpringSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class DisabledVaadinContext {

    @MockBean
    private AuthController authController;

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityVaadinConfig securityVaadinConfig;
}
```

I was playing around with the MockBeans a lot and finally figured out that this, incredibly simple, config worked:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        VaadinScopesConfig.class,
        SpringBootAutoConfiguration.class,
        SpringSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class DisabledVaadinContext {

    @MockBean
    SecurityVaadinConfig securityVaadinConfig;
}
```

Once, I've got the tests running again, I had still not solved the original problem: disabling the actual security. Well... not the entire Spring Security module, but just to the point where I do not have to be authenticated in order to access any endpoint in the tests.

The following profile works just fine for my needs.

```
@Configuration
@Primary
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
@Profile("no-security")
public class NoSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE - 8)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```